# How do I switch between projects on Git command line?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have two different projects on my GitHub account: my own and a forked repository I am contributing to. My forked copy is not up to date with the most recent change made on the master copy on the project head's account. I want to update my forked project to reflect the most recent changes, but I think my Terminal is telling me I am located in my own project. How do I switch to the forked repository in Terminal and update changes?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has a help pages for [syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).

It basically says:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git # Only the first time
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: Do I need to cd in to the project folder I need to be updated before running this command? If not, then where do I need to be? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you always have to be in your project folder for every `git` command.